# How do i add an custom activity field to an email in civimail?

Tags: civimail, activities

When i send an email to someone i need it to include activity tokens in the email. All you can use currently is contact fields. Any thoughts?

Comment: How would you determine *which* activity to take tokens from?

Comment: I would really like to know if this is possible, perhaps using status change to trigger an action. i need one party to fill in a drupal form which creates, and partially fills in, the civi activity, then a third party to fill in another drupal form automatically linked to the original activity. if anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated...

Comment: Rik - you might want to separate yours as a new question. And flesh out some more. Who needs the email? At what step, sounds like step 2. If so why can't the email be a Webform email?

Comment: And if it can't be a webform email, what is stopping using a Scheduled Reminder? Are tokens for custom fields for Activities not available for Scheduled Reminders that are based on Activity 'entity'?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve anything, but a note for future development: contributions have the same situation where it's ambiguous which contribution you're talking about if you're emailing a contact.  However, there's a nice feature for sending thank-you letters (PDF or email) that has the contribution and contact tokens.  The difference is that this is accessed from the contribution search, so you're explicitly picking the contribution.

Something similar could be done for activities: if you do an activity search, it would be nice if emails generated from there allowed for including tokens referring to the activity.  Likewise, it would be nice to have a button from the activity saying "send an email regarding this activity".

Answer (score 1):

I actually ended up writing a custom drupal module for this that pulls the custom fields and assigns them as tokens.thanks for your feedback! I will try to post the module after fully testing. - but it is possible.

Comment: yes pls do provide more info on this when you can so the community can see how you approached this

Answer (score 0):

Could you be making use of Scheduled Reminders triggered by some feature of the Activity eg Status rather than manually emailing the Activity? And if so, does that give you access to the Activity custom field token?

(more questions than answers but it does point you in an alternative direction)

Comment: Scheduled reminders triggered by a feature of the activity still doesn't provide any activity custom field tokens as far as I could see.